# Angular 4 function loses context using papaparse

Tags: angular, typescript, papaparse

I have the following code

```
httpcsv2Array(event) {
    var gethttpcsv = 
    Papa.parse('https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/e/yadyada/pub?output=csv', {
                        download: true,
                        header: true,
                        dynamicTyping: true//,
                        complete: this.importhttpcsv
            });
  }

importhttpcsv(results) {
    this.bformservice.deleteAll();

    results.data.forEach(item => {
      let tarr = item as bform;
      this.bformservice.bulkcreatebform(tarr);
    });
}
```

it appears that importhttpcsv gets launched within the context of papa.parse beacuse I get the error:
TypeError: Cannot read property 'deleteAll' of undefined

I am able to use this.bformservice.deleteAll() in other functions in this same class.

I need to access functions in a different service in order to update the database.  Any way around this?

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is need of using `Arrow function` to pretend correct `this`

```
complete: () => { 
  this.importhttpcsv();
}
```